# Mac Mini (Apple Silicon) locked at 30hz refresh rate on Benq PD3220U

Tags: mac, display

I cannot get the new Mac Mini (Apple Silicon Late 2020) to work at 60hz on my Benq PD3220U monitor. I can get 60hz at 1280x720 though. My two other MacBook Pros and an Intel NUC works great at 60hz in 3840x2160 with the same monitor.

I have tried three different Thunderbolt cables and HDMI with the same result. It seems like there is some issue with the brand new Mac graphics and this monitor. My LG 4k TV works great though with the Mac Mini at 60hz in 3840x2160. I use MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29)

Does anyone know if there is some way to get 60hz working with Benq PD3220U?

Comment: There are significant differences between your Intel NUC and your new Apple Mini.  What are the differences between the monitor and the TV.  I am only pointing there are significant differences since you made the comparison

Comment: Make sure you're using HDMI 2, or better still use DisplayPort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Mac Mini (Apple Silicon Late 2020) seems to work only at 30hz on Benq PD3220U monitor via thunderbolt 3. I can get 60hz only via HDMI. I found this video, seems to be an issue actually https://youtu.be/KXIKRLLVCw4 any workaround?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing similar issues with an external LG monitor getting 'stuck' at 30hz, which is slightly different from the question but hopefully this helps anyone else who is here having the same issue I am.

For me the only way to get it un-stuck was unplugging the power from the monitor for a bit and plugging it back in.